# Why git remote add is not working__?

Tags: git, git-bash

The git remote add is not woking. I`ve tried even the $ git remote set-url/ $ git remote set-url --add Local_1

$ git remote add local_1 \C\Users\Luciano\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Repositório_Alura_teste\Server
usage: git remote add []

```
-f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
--tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                      or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
-t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
-m, --master <branch>
                      master branch
--mirror[=(push|fetch)]
                      set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

Answer (score 0):

Git remote complains because the destination directory contains space characters, and thus are interpreted as several arguments. Try running

```bash
git remote add local_1 '\C\Users\Luciano\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Repositório_Alura_teste\Server'
```

Also when using windows slashes (`\`) in paths they need to be escaped. Generally it is better to use `/`.